# Storing key-value pairs that have a one-to-many relationship in the SESSION scope

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

A user can belong to many `Company`s which in turn have many `Department`s.

When a user logs in, I want to store in the `SESSION` scope which Departments in which Companies he belongs to.

I am currently doing it like this (the `getDepartments` query contains `CompanyName` and `DepartmentName` records that the user belongs to):

```
<cfset SESSION.Department = StructNew()/>
<cfloop query="getDepartments" group="CompanyName">
    <cfloop>
    <cfset SESSION.Department[getDepartments.CompanyName][getDepartments.DepartmentName] = StructNew()/>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

If I run the above I get an output like this:

```
struct
NESTLE
   struct
   SALES      - struct [empty]
   struct
   HR         - struct [empty]
----------------------------------------------
struct
MARS
   struct
   LOGISTICS   - struct [empty]
```

So each Department within a Company is being created a struct. And because there's no value to assign to a Department name it shows it as empty.

I think I am doing this incorrectly. But equally, I don't know of another way assign multiple Department names to a single Company name in the SESSION scope.

Any ideas?

Comment: Its only the ones the user belongs to. I didn't include the getDepartments query but its only the ones that the user belongs to!

Comment: You can store the information however you want, but the right approach here all depends on how you intend to use it. You could store the department names as a list, array or you could even leave it as a structure (though with a simple "value"). Then use `structKeyExists(struct.companyName, "theDepartmentName")` to determine if someone is a member of a particular department. But again, it all depends on how you are ultimately using the information, which you did not explain ....

Answer (score 1):

Another solution may be to create an array of departments for each company! instead of structures. Like this.

```
<cfset SESSION.Department = StructNew()/>
<cfloop query="getDepartments" group="CompanyName">
    <cfset SESSION.Department[getDepartments.CompanyName]=arrayNew(1)/>
    <cfset i=0>
    <cfloop>
        <cfset i++ />
        <cfset SESSION.Department[getDepartments.CompanyName][i] = getDepartments.DepartmentName/>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

[image]